# Rewrite rule not working for empty request_uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to make following rule work when {REQUEST_URI} is null or doesn't have any value.

```
# Redirect Legacy Site Domains
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Works for: m.example.com/success

Result: www.example.com/success

Doesn't work for: m.example.com

Result:  www.example.com/%7Brequest_uri%7D

Comment: htaccess Tester is  helpful https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the rule, try use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all the requests to `www.example.com` with the same path structure.